# Erase by value in a vector of shared pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, shared-ptr

I want to erase by value from a vector of shared ptr of string (i.e `vector<shared_ptr<string>>`) . Is there any efficient way of doing this instead of iterating the complete vector and then erasing from the iterator positions.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<shared_ptr<string>> v;
  v.push_back(make_shared<string>("aaa"));
  int j = 0,ind;
  for(auto i : v) {
    if((*i)=="aaa"){
       ind = j;
     }
    j++;
  }
 v.erase(v.begin()+ind);
}
```

Also I dont want to use memory for a map ( value vs address).

Comment: Don't use bits/c++.h and you should probably do something about not finding the string...

Comment: Do you wish to interleave insertions and deletions? Or do all the insertions happen up front, followed only by deletions and lookup?

Comment: this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053883/erase-after-performing-remove-if

Answer (score 3):

Try like that ([Erase-Remove Idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)):

```
string s = "aaa";
auto cmp = [s](const shared_ptr<string> &p) { return s == *p; };

v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp), v.end());
```

Comment: Indeed, this covers the issue of not finding the string properly.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher That's correct. Iterator passed to erase allowed to be _end()_;

Comment: I will just stress that this idiom is no way more efficient, though it is what you should use for `vectors`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way then `O(N)` - you have to find the object in a vector, and you have to iterate the vector once to find it. Does not really matter if it is a pointer or any object.

The only way to do better is to use a different data structure, which provides `O(1)` finding/removal. A `set` is the first thing that comes to mind, but that would indicate your pointers are unique. A second option would be a map, such that multiple pointers pointing to the same value exist at the same hash key.

If you do not want to use a different structure, then you are out of luck. You could have an additional structure hashing the pointers, if you want to retain the vector but also have `O(1)` access.

For example if you do use a set, and define a proper key - `hasher` or `key_equal`. probably `hasher` is enough defined as the hash for `*elementInSet`, so each pointer must point to a distinct string for example:

```
struct myPtrHash {
    size_t operator()(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& p) const {
        //Maybe we want to add checks/throw a more meaningful error if p is invalid?
        return std::hash<std::string>()(*p);
    }
};
```

such that your set is:

```
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<std::string>,myPtrHash > pointerSet;
```

Then erasing would be `O(1)` simply as:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> toErase = make_shared("aaa");
pointerSet.erase(toErase)
```

That said, if you must use a vector a more idomatic way to do this is to use [`remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) instead of iterating yourself - this will not improve time complexity though, just better practice.

Comment: what if i am using unordered_set instead of vector , any efficient way then ? @kabanus

Comment: @UddhavMishra what hash function and equality check you use in that unordered set ?

Comment: @UddhavMishra added an example, that may suit you.

Answer (score -1):

Don't include bits/stdc++.h, and since you're iterating through the hole vector, you should be using std::for_each with a lambda.